# AWS with SSMS connection

Tags: pyspark, ssms, amazon-rds, aws-glue, amazon-athena

small question. Is there any way to connect SQL Server table from aws athena directly? Because i have a  table data (30M records) and want to validate some informations. Rather than uploading data into s3 can’t i make connection between aws and SSMS ? I made connection between SSMS and VM locally and made dataframe. But i cant do same thing with aws and SSMS. I will appreciate if you can give a solution for me. Thanks

I have tried many ways such as making an RDS,EC2 instances, lambda fuctions but i couldn't find a solution

Answer (score 1):

Choose Data Sources from Athena menu

Create connector to DB Flavour required. Its called Athena Federated Querying

[SQL Connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6IM4J.png)

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/connect-to-a-data-source-lambda-deploying.html